# Visual Studio - Assert not stopping when fails

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mstest

Just moved from VS2010 Professional to Premium.

When I hit a failing Assert using MSTEST, it doesn't stop in the debugger anymore (it does produce a correct fail in the Test Results)

**Problem:**  How to get the debugger to stop on the failing assert when I run tests

[image]

Comment: Also be aware that a System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert failure does *not* fail a unit test running in the Visual Studio test framework.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to do this you'll need to do the following

- Disable Just My Code: Tools -> Options -> Debugger.  Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"
- Enable Break on throw: Debug -> Exceptions.  Check "thrown" for CLR exceptions.

Comment: Tools, Options, Debugging, General, I found that ticking:  Enable Just My Code (not ticking show all members.. and ticking Warm if no user....).. gave me what I was looking for.  No need to Enable Break on throw.  Cheers.

Comment: **For VS 2017**, see Debug -> Windows ->  Exception Settings... or ctrl-alt-e

Comment: The CLR thing is the one that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before when I run failed tests with (CTRL + R, F) which just runs the failed tests where (CTRL + R, CTRL + F) debugs the tests and breaks when the assert fails. Let me know if this helps.